# Cesàro means of divergent series

Tags: divergent-series, cesaro-summable

Does $\sum \limits_{n=2}^\infty n$ have a greater Cesàro mean than $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty n$?

If not, then is there any *other* sense of "mean" in which the former's mean is greater than the latter's?

(Sorry if this question makes no sense. I have no idea what I'm doing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have no limit, so one could say, they are both infinite. And whether $\infty-1 \ne \infty$ makes some sense at all is up to some, I'd say, ***very*** specific context - if such context exists at all...

Note, that the Cesaro-summing gives "means" in the sense, that the partial means of the partial sums converge to some fixed number. So it is most used in the case of alternating signs, for instance $s_1 \underset{\mathcal {Ces}}{=}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n $, and $s_2 \underset{\mathcal {Ces}}{=} \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n n $ . And then indeed we arrive at $s_1 \ne s_2$

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. If you have time for a quick follow-up question: what is the Cesaro mean of an alternating harmonic series? And does this depend on the order of the terms in the series?

Comment: @theodoricus : $\ln(2)$. Even more general: ***once*** the cesaro-sum/mean converges at all, then it converges to the value which is expected by the other computation  / estimation techniques. And the alternating harmonic series converges itself to the same value $\ln(2)$

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure that I understand the difference between cesaro-sum and cesaro-mean. This wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesàro_mean) distinguishes between the sum and the mean. I'm interested only in the mean. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I now see why the Cesaro sum converges to ln(2). But why doesn't the Cesaro *mean* converge to 0?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure at the moment, but isn't the mean not just the $n$'th partial (Cesaro) sum divided by $n$? Then a finite Cesaro-sum $s_n$ for $n \to \infty $ should go to $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n / n = 0$

Comment: Hmm, also I suspect that at the date of my answer I might not have thought your question correctly to the end because I end with consideration of the sums, not means. I'll look again at this when I've more time